# Touchpad Settings

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad

I'm using Kubuntu 23.10. I can configure the touchpad through system settings with a shortcut key (I can toggle on/off). However, when the touchpad is disabled and I restart the laptop, the touchpad becomes active again. I have to disable it again every time. Can you help?

Kind regards

Comment: not used kubuntu before, but does this work? `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'disabled'` alternatively if you don't want to use cli then you can install dconf-editor (`sudo apt install dconf-editor`) and navigate to the path in the command and toggle it through the GUI

Comment: It won't work :/